# Output gene positions from GenBank file

Tags: skbio

Is it possible to output the gene location for a CDS feature or do I need to parse the 'location' or 'complement' field myself?

For example,

```
seq = Sequence.read(genbank_fp, format='genbank')
for feature in seq.metadata['FEATURES']:
    if feature['type_'] == 'CDS':
        if 'location' in feature:
            print 'location = ', feature['location']
        elif 'complement' in feature:
            print 'location = ', feature['complement']
        else:
            raise ValueError('positions for gene %s not found' % feature['protein_id'])
```

would output:

location =  <1..206

location =  687..3158

for [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Sitemap/samplerecord.html) sample GenBank file.

This functionality is possible in BioPython (see [this thread](https://www.biostars.org/p/142972/)) where I can output the positions already parsed (ex. start = 687, end = 3158).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the example, you can get the `Sequence` object for the feature only, using the following code:

```
# column index in positional metadata
col = feature['index_']
loc = seq.positional_metadata[col]
feature_seq = seq[loc]
# if the feature is on reverse strand
if feature['rc_']:
    feature_seq = feature_seq.reverse_complement()
```

Note: the GenBank parser is newly added in the development branches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However I'm looking for the actual start and end positions of the gene (not the gene sequence itself). To extend on your answer, I need to find the index of the first and last True element in the loc Series: `start_pos = loc[loc == True].index[0]; end_pos = loc[loc == True].index[-1]`